# Как выровнять иконку по уровню текста?

Tags: css

На сайте https://voyagecosmetics.ru/ есть сверху номер телефона и иконка телефона. Надо чтобы было ровно. Как это сделать.

Могу добавить, что иконка телефона стоит отдельно от ее серого фона, что усложняет выравнивание.

CSS серого круга

```
.header-features > li .fa {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 7px;
    display: block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #666;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

CSS иконки

```
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте применить: display: flex; align-items: center; к обертке иконки и текста. Это выровнит содержимое по центру

Comment: не помогло ---------

Comment: тогда что вам надо выровнять? "Чтоб все было ровно", весьма расплывчато

Comment: потому что в .header-features нужно display: flex; тоже добавить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, нужно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если да, то :

```
style.css - 1903

.header-features {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}


 style.css - 1910

.header-features > li {
   margin-right: 20px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```